# HTML button from a webpage to a specific item from a specific Amazon seller

Tags: html

A friend of mine used wix to build a small site selling t-shirts. He also put them on amazon.

Is there any way to create buttons to send the buyer to amazon to purchase the item from my friend.

He isn't selling unique items so there will be multiple sellers, also wix is a static site generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visit the Amazon page for the item you want to link to, you can copy its URL straight from the browser's address bar. You can delete the parts of the URL starting with `/ref=...`, which are used by Amazon to track visitors and aren't necessary. [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fpwt-IzASf0) explains how to create a linked button in Wix.

For example, if you search Amazon for `stack overflow robot t shirt`, you'll end up at a page that looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of amazon.com page]

The first two items are identical, but are sold by two different vendors. The second one (FZLB) is 1¢ cheaper, so let's go there:

[image: Screenshot of page for the FZLB T shirt]

The highlighted part of the address bar shows what you need to copy. Paste this into the "Link To" box in the Wix button settings dialog. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks I thought that was the way to go but was worried how brittle it might be. Will the URL ever change?

Comment: It shouldn't change at all. In fact, you don't even need the product name in the URL; just `amazon.com/dp/«product ID»` is sufficient. However, keeping the product name intact may be beneficial in terms of SEO.

Comment: How do you know it's going to be the page from that specific seller? I assume each product can be sold by multiple sellers.. Therefore you would need the seller variable also. And this will send them to the specific Amazon product page, not adding the item to the cart (and therefore skipping the product page)

Comment: @Malachi As I understand it, the path fragment following `dp/` in the URL identifies a unique product from a unique vendor. The readable part before that is just window dressing, and doesn't need to be there at all. The original product shown above is no longer available, but you can verify for yourself that the following URLs all lead to the same product from the same vendor: (a) http://www.amazon.com/Jeff-Atwood-Effective-Programming-Paperback/dp/B00L8HBW7E (b) http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00L8HBW7E (c) http://www.amazon.com/Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet/dp/B00L8HBW7E

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage Thanks for checking into it. I haven't looked at it myself yet, since I'm trying something else first and am having some success with the OfferListingId, but that's a whole different story...